# .bashrc not run when SSH-ing in as a user who has home dir encryption

Tags: 12.04, ssh, encryption, ecryptfs, bashrc

If I SSH into an Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS server as a user with home dir encryption, I get a really plain shell (no default `.bashrc` run). If I log in via console (of course causing the home directory to be decrypted) and then SSH in *while* logged into the console, the `.bashrc` script will have been run and the SSH experience will be normal... I've solved the problem of `authorized_keys` being encrypted during login attempts, but how do I now solve this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the answers of http://askubuntu.com/q/115497/236?