# How to auto-login on Ubuntu 16.04 Server?

Tags: server, 16.04, ssh, login

I have a server computer running Ubuntu 16.04 Server, and it is running headless, so it is rather frustrating to restart the computer and have to login before I am able to SSH into the server. I've seen other articles but someone noted the process changed in 16.04 and it no longer pertains to editing the /etc/init/tty1.conf file. What should I do to be able to auto-login to the server at boot?

Comment: There should be no need to be logged in locally before logging in remotely via SSH - are you using key-based SSH authentication, and if so are your keys stored in an encrypted home directory by any chance?

Comment: I didn't think auto-login was necessary, but yes the keys are stored in an encrypted home folder.

Comment: See [User Home directory encryption - files that must remain un-encrypted like authorized_keys](http://askubuntu.com/questions/604674/user-home-directory-encryption-files-that-must-remain-un-encrypted-like-author) - I'd recommend using a location like /etc/ssh/<user>/

Comment: Ahh alright, so just move the authorized_keys file to a new folder under the username?

Comment: You will need to edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file accordingly e.g. `AuthorizedKeysFile     /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys`  - see [Troubleshooting - Encrypted Home Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting) in the SSH section of the Ubuntu Community Wiki

Comment: Alright, now how do I login to my home folder when SSH-ing on reboot? I am prompted with the user@hostname but it is not my home folder.

Comment: You will need to run `ecryptfs-mount-private` manually I think - see [Encrypted Home directories + SSH Key Authentication](https://stephen.rees-carter.net/thought/encrypted-home-directories-ssh-key-authentication) for example

Comment: Interesting, I took a look at the article and followed it, however when trying to SSH on reboot the command hangs and times out. Any thoughts?